# How to set schema in Python to use a json file on BigQuery?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, schema

I am looking for a way how the schema is set with a json file in Python on Big Query. The following document says I can set it with Schema field one by one, but I want to find out more efficient way.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas

Autodetect would be skeptical to make it in this case.
I will appreciate it if you helped me.

Comment: Do you mean that you provide a JSON that describe your schema? And you want to match this definition in the field definition of BigQuery?

Comment: Yes, I do. Is there any way to make it true what you said?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a JSON file with columns/data types and use the below code to build BigQuery Schema.

JSON File (schema.json):

```
[
    {
        "name": "emp_id",
        "type": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
        "name": "emp_name",
        "type": "STRING"
    }
]
```

Python Code:

```
import json
from google.cloud import bigquery

bigquerySchema = []
with open('schema.json') as f:
    bigqueryColumns = json.load(f)
    for col in bigqueryColumns:
        bigquerySchema.append(bigquery.SchemaField(col['name'], col['type']))

print(bigquerySchema)
```

Comment: Does it still works if the `schema.json` file has nested fields?

Answer (score 0):

Soumendra Mishra is already helpful, but here is a bit more general version that can optionally accept addition fields such as `mode` or `description`:

JSON File (schema.json):

```json
[
    {
        "name": "emp_id",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "REQUIRED"
    },
    {
        "name": "emp_name",
        "type": "STRING",
        "description": "Description of this field"
    }
]
```

Python Code:

```py
import json
from google.cloud import bigquery

table_schema = []
# open JSON file read only
with open('schema.json', 'r') as f:
    table_schema = json.load(f)
    for entry in table_schema:
        # rename key; bigquery.SchemaField expects `field` to be called `field_type`
        entry["field_type"] = entry.pop("type")
        # ** effectively provides data as argument:value pairs (e.g. name="emp_id")
        table_schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField(**entry))
```